# Returning last inserted id from MySql

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I'm having a bit of trouble with the following query:

```sql
START TRANSACTION;

SET @LASTID = 0;

INSERT INTO `Accounts` (`Col1`,`col2`,`col3`,`col4`)
                VALUES (@param1,@param2,@param3,@param4);

SET @LASTID = last_insert_id(); -- This is what I need

INSERT INTO `Users` (`usr1`,`usr2`,`usr3`,`usr4`)
             VALUES (@usr1,@usr2,@usr3,@usr4);

SELECT @LASTID;
COMMIT;
```

Basically, I need to return the last inserted ID from the accounts table, however when running SELECT @LASTID, MySql returns a blob rather than a single value, which I'm having trouble accessing in C# asp.net

Is there any simple way to get this value as an int / varchar? Converting from blobs in code i feel is overkill, and I'd like to leave that lifting to the Mysql server.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use

```
 SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Comment: I can't use LAST_INSERT_ID() as that would return the result from the insert into the Users table... Or, can I run the select in place of the SET @LASTID ?

Comment: call it once , only after insertion to accounts table

Comment: Thank you Haim. I was unsure as to returning a select before the final insert query. I thought that the final insert into the users table would return something thus meaning the previous select would be overwritten. Thanks again for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Change the last statement into:

```
SELECT CAST(@LASTID AS integer) as last_id_from_accounts;
```